# linq to sql: do I need to explicitly create a transaction?

Tags: linq-to-sql, transactions

Every time when I need to execute more than one query at work by L2S, I'm creating explicitly a transaction using TransactionScope. Today my colleague told me that, he never creating manually a transactions, because the L2S doing it at the SubmitChanges level. I was confussing, so I have done some sample code to test it. As I far I understood th result - he was right. 
My question is, was it available from the beginning of linq to sql or was this added in some .net version/service pack? 
In the net, there are plenty of samples of how to use a TransactionScope with the L2S, so I'm not sure that, every one of these people could missed it?

Comment: L2S has created transactions for SubmitChanges since the early betas. This is what enables the ability to roll back an action when an exception occurs (see `SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicit TransactionScopes do have value if you want to wrap multiple queries and multiple calls to SaveChanges in a single Transaction...but if you are saving an object graph (which will generate multiple insert/update statements to the DB), all those statements will be wrapped in a Transaction automatically when SaveChanges is called.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you make all of your changes and then call `SubmitChanges()` a single time, a transaction is automatically created.

The only time you need to worry about a `TransactionScope` is when you make several calls to `SubmitChanges()` or you need a transaction that works across multiple contexts.